# Repost screencasts for Lubuntu? (blip have removed them)

Tags: lubuntu, documentation, screencast

Lubuntu documentation lists quite a few [screencasts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Screencasts) - however since Nov 7, 2013 links are redirected to a blip [account removed notice](http://support.blip.tv/entries/23007795).

Looking at their [terms of use](http://blip.tv/terms), perhaps they considered it was "advertising a product" ??

Regardless of blip, are the screencasts for Lubuntu likely to be reposted (presumably, on Youtube or similar?)

(PS: not sure if this question belongs in [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) or not...)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the same videos are available at YouTube.
See
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-October/005730.html
and
http://www.youtube.com/llelectronics

Comment: Thanks!  I made a playlist for the Lubuntu ones, since our good friend Leszek has many videos and not all of them are Lubuntu related.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYjFuFSECHE&list=PLPUJou5bB-9ZvGZEQMShyoJe-KsAeAT2q&index=1